# Placement of Python counter within class/function

Tags: python

I have the code below. I want to write 40 numbered output files (`outfile`) with 100 lines each. The while loop is supposed to check when the counter reaches a 100. But my `counter = counter + 1` does not do the job. The `counter` stays at `1`.

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        for i in range(40): # create max 40 outfiles
            outfile = (projname + "_" + str(i+1) + "_output.json")
            counter = 0
            while counter <= 100:
                try:
                    with open(outfile, 'a') as f:
                        f.write(data)
                        counter = counter + 1
                        print("\rAppending tweet " + str(counter) + " to " + str(outfile), end="")
                        return True
                except BaseException as e:
                    print("Error on_data: " % str(e))
                    return True
            else:
                break
```

Comment: and you see a long long list of `error on data ...` ?

Comment: because you are returning right after incrementing counter... so counter will always be 1 or 0

Comment: You are `Return`ing in the first iteration..

Comment: Actually, the `try` does what it should. It executes the `f.write(data)` correctly. It is just that the counter does not increase.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Aha. When should I `Return`?

Comment: [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) effectively quits the function, so it would make sense to do it at the end of whatever the function is supposed to do.

Comment: This is a bit of an odd way to deal with a `StreamListener` from tweepy. Won't `data` consist of a single tweet?

Comment: @asongtoruin This code is not my full script. I get `data` and write each item (tweet) as a line in a json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the liberty to re-write your code a bit.

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        for i in range(40):  # create max 40 outfiles
            outfile = (projname + "_" + str(i+1) + "_output.json")
            with open(outfile, 'a') as f:
                for counter in range(100):
                    f.write(data)
                    print("\rAppending tweet " + str(counter) + " to " + str(outfile), end="")
        return True
```

As you might notice there are a few things that are done differently now.

1. No need for a `while` if you know how many times you need to execute a loop.
2. Opening and closing a file every time you want to write a line is very wasteful, so do it once per file
3. I do not see a point for your `try` block.. What is it that should be tried because it might fail?
4. Why the `else` at the end?

There is a chance I missinterpreted some of your code and removed features that should be there. If that is the case or if you have any questions, please let me know.

**Note: Keep in mind that `.write()` is not like `print()` and does not append a newline character automatically. So your script will write everything in a single line unless `data` contains newlines.**

And I final thing. `data` does not change in each iteration. You are writing the same thing 100 times in each file. Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: the exception might be some kind of encoding issue? Guessing slightly.

Comment: @asongtoruin I would still run the script like this; at least initially to see what kind of errors it might throw and then try catching them if catching them makes sense in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! This does what it should. The exception has to do with some kind of error that the Twitter API may throw (I got parts of the code from [here](https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/03/02/mining-twitter-data-with-python-part-1/).